# JavaScript 304 Not Modified issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am having issues with a simple project I am doing. I am trying to play around with some JavaScript, HTML5, SVG drawing using Raphael.js. When I try loading the HTML page with the embedded JavaScript files I get a blank page in my browser. I checked Firebug and Chrome developer tools and I keep getting a 304 Not Modified error for my scripts and my HTML page.

I'm running this project on my local server using MAMP on a Mac OSX.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>g.Raphael Practise</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="g.pie-min.js"/></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #canvas-container {
                width: 500;
                border: 1px solid #aaa;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas-container"></div>
    </body>


</html>
```

This is the content of "myscript.js":

```
    window.onload = function() {
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("canvas-container"), 500, 500);

    paper.piechart(250, 250, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2]);

}
```

Comment: Any JS erros? What content do you expect from a nearly-empty webpage? 304 is not an issue, that is expected behavior.

Comment: [`304 Not Modified`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_304) is definitely no error! If your page stays blank (but is not expected to), show us the contents of your scripts!

Comment: I've added the content of "myscript.js" the other two are JavaScript libraries from http://g.raphaeljs.com/ and http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Your example worked perfectly for me (or at least, it draws _something_), so double-check that the libraries are all where you think they are (in the same directory as the HTML file). Put some visible HTML markup on the page to ensure that it's actually loading at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs of g.raphaeljs](http://g.raphaeljs.com/):

> include `raphael.js`, **`g.raphael.js` and** any (or all) of `g.line.js`, `g.bar.js`, `g.dot.js` and `g.pie.js` into your HTML page

[Your current code](http://jsfiddle.net/jgFdF/) doesn't really show an empty page, but you have to [include the gRaphaël basic script as well](http://jsfiddle.net/jgFdF/1/) to make it work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="g.raphael-min.js"/></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="g.pie-min.js"/></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I added the g.raphael script and it's now working somewhat. I think my browsers are caching the older markup because when I try opening up the page it shows the old markup without the g.raphael script.